# Change port of SonarQube installed via homebrew

Tags: sonarqube, homebrew

Where to find sonar.properties file in the sonarqube installed via homebrew to change the value of `sonar.web.port`

Answer (score 2):

1. when you install sonarqube via homebrew, it is installed at following location `/usr/local/Cellar/sonarqube`
2. Thus sonar.properties file can be found at `/usr/local/Cellar/sonarqube/8.0/libexec/conf` folder
3. In order to change port of SonarQube, edit `sonar.properties` file by changing the value of `sonar.web.port` to desired port number from `9000`